# reg . Teradata SQL / BTEQ / BTET . Export to an excel report with 2 tabs using BTEQ

Tags: sql, database, transactions, teradata, data-warehouse

I can do this beautifully in `SQL Assistant` and the result will show up  in 2 tabs which can be saved to an `excel` file with 2 tabs.

```
BT; 
sel <query1>
;
Sel <query2>
;
ET
```

I want to know if something similar can be done in `BTEQ`. I am prolly hoping against hope but I thought I'd had done my asking around. Using `BTEQ` I can export 2 different queries to 2 different `excel` files , and that is fine. I want to know if, its poss. to export the o/p of 2 queries into a single `excel` file with 2 tabs 

and a small corollary question : In `SQL Assistant`, is it poss to export  the result of 2  queries run serially to a 2 tab , `excel` report by some method *other than* `BTET`
( P.S `BTET` in `BTEQ` is meaningless , I am using it only in `SQL Ass`. So dont mean  using `BTET`  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Assistant there's a setting `Tools -> Options -> General -> Use a separate Answer window for` which is set by default to `Each Query`. When you run multiple Select either using F5 or F9 you get all result sets as tabs in a single window and the `File -> Save` then asks for *Save all sheets?* This is independent of `BT/ET`.

In BTEQ there's no way to get multiple results into one file, in fact there's no support for Excel, it's only the very old [DIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Interchange_Format) format which doesn't support multiple tabs.

Comment: Hi Dieter : I quite dont have this op on `14.0. ` ( `Tools -> Options -> General -> Use a separate Answer window for`). I downgraded that else I'd loose `vecomp` & other utils that they stripped as they moved ahead.  ( they wont let me use a combo of  `15.1 SQL Ass` and `ODBC & CLIV2 from 14.1`. Latter are needed for utilities to work. TY

Comment: @user1874594: Well, there's still `Visual Explain` in TTU15.10, I got an entry for it in `Tools. So you must upgrade all TTU, not only SQLA. Or what else are you missing?

Comment: `vcomp` and others were'nt even packaged  for admin or anyone else on our internal website. I could'nt see Visual Explain in 15.0 or so on  Teradata. It might have returned back in 15.1. I will check.TY again

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar problems. 
What you can do is use BTEQ to export the data to a CSV and then use a VBS script to open up the Excel file and copy the CSV in a new worksheet. 
First you need to delete the old one otherwise it will get renamed.

```
Option Explicit 
Dim MyPath, objExcel, objWorkbook, objSourceData, objTargetSheet

MyPath = "C:\Users\user\"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Application.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(MyPath & "ExcelFile.xlsx")

objExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Sheets("worksheetname").Delete
objExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Set objSourceData = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(MyPath & "csvfilename.csv")

objSourceData.sheets(1).Copy objworkbook.Sheets(objworkbook.Sheets.Count)

objworkbook.Save
objworkbook.Close

objExcel.Application.Quit

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Thank You. In my situation the report was coming from UNIX and being sent using TWS. So there wasnt that chance to meddle in  , using a VBA. So had to convert that into a 2 Attachment report.But thanks for the suggestion - gave the 1 up.Wish I could up it more !